# Iterate through all spreadsheets in the folder and edit with this code?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am looking to loop the code provided through all of the spreadsheets in a given folder.  I'm just not sure how to do it.  Every way I try to iterate through the folder errors out.  I have tried like 10 different variations.

I am going to use a stand alone script that I can insert the ID number of the folder.
Any ideas?
Thanks so much for any help you can give.  I'm still learning, but getting better. :)
Brandon

```js
function dataUpdate() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // Trying to iterate through all spreadsheets in a folder rather than using .getactivespreadsheet().
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange(2,7);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets()[3];
  var cell1 = sheets.getRange(7,8);
  var cell2 = sheets.getRange(7,9);
  
  cell.setValue('RTI')
  sheets.setName("RTI Data");
  sheets.getRange(4, 8).setValue('Cell Value');
  sheets.getRange(5, 8).setValue('1');
  sheets.getRange(6, 8).setValue('2');
  sheets.getRange(7, 8).setValue('3');
  sheets.getRange(5, 9).setValue('Tier 1');
  sheets.getRange(6, 9).setValue('Tier 2');
  sheets.getRange(7, 9).setValue('Tier 3');
 
  cell1.setHorizontalAlignment("center").setBackground("#f0f0f0");
  cell2.setHorizontalAlignment("center").setBackground("#f0f0f0");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for getFolderById() or getFoldersByName(), plus SpreadsheetApp.openById(), you'll figure it out pretty easily.

Edit: Made a stub:

```
// Iterates trough all files in given folder and logs the A1 in the first sheet in all of them
var folderId = "sdoijawodkhqoud98y12eh";
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
var files = folders.getFiles();
while (files .hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next(),
      ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()),
      sheet = ss.getSheets()[0],
      A1Value = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log(A1Value);
}
```

Also, try to work with more than a range at a time, don't do a lot of setValue() and getValue(), instead work with array, I would treat it as such:

```
sheetRange = ss.getRange(1, 1, 7, 9); 
sheetVals = sheetRange.getValues();
sheetVals[ 1 ][ 6 ] = "RTI"
sheetVals[ 3 ][ 7 ] = "Cell Value"

// ... and so on...

sheetRange.setValues(sheetVals);
sheets.getRange(7, 8, 1, 2).setHorizontalAlignment("center").setBackground("#f0f0f0");
```

As seen in good practices: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices

Comment: Thanks for help and info on best practices.  I really appreciate it!